# How to render NotFound page if the entered path is not matching the route in module federation react micro frontends?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router-dom, webpack-module-federation

Usually, we will show the NotFound page to the user if the provided path is not matching using the below code

`<Route path={"*"} component={NotFound} />`

But when I add this, it always navigates me to the home page which is `/`.

Not rendering the NotFound component.

Please help me to solve this one. The code is in this repository https://github.com/dhanushkumarsivaji/microfront-end

**Webpack Code Files: -**

**container:** **(HOST)**

**app.js**

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
  StylesProvider,
  createGenerateClassName,
} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

import Progress from './components/Progress';
import Header from './components/Header';

const MarketingLazy = lazy(() => import('./components/MarketingApp'));
const AuthAppLazy = lazy(() => import('./components/AuthApp'));

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
  productionPrefix: 'co',
});

const history = createBrowserHistory();

function NotFound() {
  return (
    <h1>
        Not Found Page
    </h1>
  )
}

export default () => {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <StylesProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>
        <div>
          <Header/>
          <Suspense fallback={<Progress />}>
            <Switch>
              <Route path='/auth' component={AuthAppLazy} />
              <Route path="/" component={MarketingLazy} />
              <Route path={"*"} component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
          </Suspense>
        </div>
      </StylesProvider>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

**webpack.common.js**

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env'],
            plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
    }),
  ],
};
```

**webpack.dev.js**

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common');
const packageJson = require('../package.json');

const devConfig = {
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 8080,
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: 'index.html',
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'container',
      remotes: {
        marketing: 'marketing@http://localhost:8081/remoteEntry.js',
        auth: 'auth@http://localhost:8082/remoteEntry.js',
      },
      shared: packageJson.dependencies,
    }),
  ],
};

module.exports = merge(commonConfig, devConfig);
```

**marketing: (SUB APPS)**

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
  StylesProvider,
  createGenerateClassName,
} from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import Landing from './components/Landing';
import Pricing from './components/Pricing';

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
  productionPrefix: 'ma',
});

export default ({ history }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <StylesProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/pricing" component={Pricing} />
            <Route path="/" component={Landing} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </StylesProvider>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**webpack.common.js**

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env'],
            plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

webpack.dev.js

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common');
const packageJson = require('../package.json');

const devConfig = {
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8081/',
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 8081,
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'marketing',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      exposes: {
        './MarketingApp': './src/bootstrap',
      },
      shared: packageJson.dependencies,
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
    }),
  ],
};

module.exports = merge(commonConfig, devConfig);
```

And below is the package version I have used:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "marketing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --config config/webpack.dev.js",
    "build": "webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.15.8",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.3.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack": "^5.57.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.3.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

**Routing Problems**

And another problem in when I add the `/` route at the top like this

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/" component={MarketingLazy} />
  <Route path='/auth' component={AuthAppLazy} />
  <Route path={"*"} component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

the components which are in the `/auth` route is not rendering, in this case only the `/` route component is rendering but the path is changing in the browser.

But when I put the `/` at the bottom like this, everything works fine

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='/auth' component={AuthAppLazy} />
  <Route path="/" component={MarketingLazy} />
  <Route path={"*"} component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

How can I resolve these issues.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `path="*"` route is effectively unreachable because the `"/"` above it also matches any route.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/auth" component={AuthAppLazy} />
  <Route path="/" component={MarketingLazy} /> // <-- matches "/*"
  <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />      // <-- matches "/*" and unreachable
</Switch>
```

When you moved `<Route path="/" component={MarketingLazy} />` to the top of the routes it then also made `"/auth"` path unreachable.

The `Switch` renders ***the first*** child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location. This means that path order and specificity matters. If the app renders any page on `"/"` and also wants to define an *even less specific* "catch-all" route then it needs to ***exactly*** match `"/"` *then* allow for the general fallback.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/auth" component={AuthAppLazy} />
  <Route path="/" exact component={MarketingLazy} /> // <-- matches "/" exactly
  <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />            // <-- matches "/*" and reachable
</Switch>
```

Comment: is there any way to fix this issue ?

Comment: @SDK Sorry, what is the issue you are asking about now?

Comment: have to show the NotFound component if the entered path is not matching any route like 404 page . Currently, it's falling back to '/' route.

Comment: @SDK I see. So even after adding the `exact` prop to the `"/"` route it's not working? It almost sounds like the server/hosting service is *changing* the requested URL from `"http....../somePage"` to just `"http......./"`. In other words, is the requested app route/page getting dropped prior to the React app being served up?

Comment: the url path changes to ```/somePage``` on the browser but it renders the ```/```  path component instead of showing component added in this route ```<Route path='*' component={NotFound} />```

Comment: @SDK And you made the `"/"` path "exact", i.e. `<Route path="/" exact component={MarketingLazy} />`, and it still matches it when the path is `"/somePage"`?

Comment: if I add exact the routing inside the sub-apps not working properly

Comment: @SDK Can you clarify what you mean by "sub-apps not working properly"? Is `MarketingLazy` rendering other descendent routes? If this is the case then `path="/"` without `exact` and `path="*"` are incompatible. The solution is to change `path="/"` to something more specific like `path="/market"` so it is disambiguated from `"*"`.

Comment: Exactly, MarketingLazy renders other descendent routes. Got it, is that how Route works?

Comment: @SDK That's how route matching works. If you are exactly matching the parent/root route this necessarily precludes matching descendant routes.